# Can I use old kernel module on newer kernel version

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to replace centos 6.6 system with centos 7.2, but my kernel module for centos 6.6(kernel 2.6.32) dose not work on centos 7.2(kernel 3.10.0).
There is no source code and I am just a server engineer, not a programmer.
Could you please help me... is there any good solution?
For example, kernel module converter 2.6.32 => 3.10.0, or some hacks to force loading old kernel module...

Comment: It is not likely that every aspect of the kernel module interface itself has stayed compatible when Linux went 3.0 (though the main overhaul was in 2.6, and 3.0 is really less major than the new version number implies).  To "convert", recompile against a current kernel, probably with some changes to the source.

Answer (score 1):

You can, depending on the kernels.
You can also force load it.  But if you force load it your system might crash, depending on how you do it.
I tried that with mint 17 and mint 18.